# Foreign Key not storing in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

I have adatabase like this

```
====Group=====
id
name

====Member====
id
group_id
firstname
lastname
membersince


Now as group_id is foreign key then when I will save Group tabale then the group_id should be save with that number.
In relations I have made relations for Group is



     public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'member' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Member', 'groupid'),
    );
  }
```

In Member Model my relations is just like this

```
 public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Group','groupid'),
    );
      }
```

Now as I am going to save the two models in a single form (the example is here[[http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models]](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models))the two models are saved successfully but the foreign key is not stored.So can some one please tell me where I am doing wrong?

[Code For Controller]
Group Controller

```
<?php

class GroupController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
   * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
   */
  public $layout='//layouts/column2';

  /**
   * @return array action filters
   */
  public function filters()
  {
    return array(
      'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
  }

  /**
   * Specifies the access control rules.
   * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
   * @return array access control rules
   */
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
      ),
      array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Displays a particular model.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
   */
  public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new model.
   * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   */
  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Group;
    $member=new Member;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Group'],$_POST['Member']))
    {
      //Populate input data to $Group and $Member
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Group'];
      $member->attributes=$_POST['Member'];

      //Validate both $Group and $Member
      //$validate = $model->validate();
      //$validate = $member->validate() && validate;

#      if($validate){
#        ($model->save() & $member->save())
#        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
#      }
      if($model->save() & $member->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'member'=>$member,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Updates a particular model.
   * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
   */
  public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $member = Member::model()->findByPk( $member['name'] );
    //$member =  new Member;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Group'],$_POST['Member'])) {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Group'];
    $member->attributes=$_POST['Member'];

      if($model->save()&$member->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'member'=>$member,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Deletes a particular model.
   * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
   */
  public function actionDelete($id)
  {
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
      // we only allow deletion via POST request
      $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

      // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
      if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
      throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
  }

  /**
   * Lists all models.
   */
  public function actionIndex()
  {
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Group');
    $this->render('index',array(
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Manages all models.
   */
  public function actionAdmin()
  {
    $model=new Group('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Group']))
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Group'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
   * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
   * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
   */
  public function loadModel($id)
  {
    $model=Group::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
      throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
  }

  /**
   * Performs the AJAX validation.
   * @param CModel the model to be validated
   */
  protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='group-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
  }
}
```

Member Controller

```
<?php

class MemberController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
   * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
   */
  public $layout='//layouts/column2';

  /**
   * @return array action filters
   */
  public function filters()
  {
    return array(
      'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
  }

  /**
   * Specifies the access control rules.
   * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
   * @return array access control rules
   */
  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
      array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array('create','update'),
        'users'=>array('@'),
      ),
      array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
      ),
      array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array('*'),
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Displays a particular model.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
   */
  public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new model.
   * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   */
  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Member;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
      if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Updates a particular model.
   * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
   */
  public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
      if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Deletes a particular model.
   * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
   * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
   */
  public function actionDelete($id)
  {
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
      // we only allow deletion via POST request
      $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

      // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
      if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
      throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
  }

  /**
   * Lists all models.
   */
  public function actionIndex()
  {
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Member');
    $this->render('index',array(
      'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Manages all models.
   */
  public function actionAdmin()
  {
    $model=new Member('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Member']))
      $model->attributes=$_GET['Member'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
      'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }

  /**
   * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
   * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
   * @param integer the ID of the model to be loaded
   */
  public function loadModel($id)
  {
    $model=Member::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
      throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
  }

  /**
   * Performs the AJAX validation.
   * @param CModel the model to be validated
   */
  protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
  {
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='member-form')
    {
      echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
      Yii::app()->end();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to see your controller

Comment: I have updated the code for controller..So please help me out

Comment: I don't see where you're saving 2 records... in addition, it would be nice to see the form

Comment: Do you still need some help with this?  If so, are you trying to set the group_id for the Member model and having problems?  I just did that recently, so can post some sample code ...

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you find a solution to this? I'm using `$form->activeDropDownList(
           $model,
           'position_type_id',
           CHtml::listData(PositionType::model()->findAll(),'id','name')
       );` to generate my drop down list and though it populates correctly, it does not save the value that is passed back to the controller. I can print out the value in the POST variable and it is correctly named.