# Relations In Yii

Tags: php, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Foreign Key not storing in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967895/foreign-key-not-storing-in-yii)

I have a database like this

```
====Group=====
id
name

====Member====
id
group_id
firstname
lastname
membersince
```

Now I used this relations in models.

**Group Model**

```
 public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'member' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Member', 'group_id'),
    );
  }
```

**Member Model**

```
 public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Group', 'group_id'),
    );
  }
```

So can some one tell me is this relation is right or am I missing something any help and suggestios will be highly appreciable.

Comment: The relation should be ok. Which sort of issue are you experiencing?

Comment: Looks correct to me. What problem do you have?

Comment: Regarding what issue I am facing is asked in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967895/foreign-key-not-storing-in-yii. I had a doubt that might be there some problem in relations so I asked that. Can you please check that link if you want to help me ut.